# how to get rows before and after from specific value in column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe , first step i will find row in column A where value is greater than or equal to 0.9 in second step i will get rows 4 rows before and after when value of A greater or equal to 0.9, (note:4 rows before and 4rows after and also include row with value greater or equal 0.9, so every time when condition meet get 9 rows and apply some function for calculation)

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,0.91,2,2,2,2,0.95,2],'flag':[1,1,0,1,1,1,5,1,1,0,1,1,1]})


out_put

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,0.91,2,2,2,2],'flag':[0,1,1,1,5,1,1,0,1]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly use boolean masking and check your Frst condition and get the index of it by using `.index` attribute:

```
df=df[df['A']>=0.9]    #1st condition fullfilled
```

if we dont know exact value then we can check the value between the exact value and slightly more value and get the index of 1st occurence of value for your 2nd condition:

```
position=df[df['A'].between(0.9,0.99)].index[0]
```

Finally make use of `loc[]` accessor and `reset_index()` method:

```
resultdf=df.loc[position-4:position+4,:].reset_index(drop=True)  
#2nd condition fullfilled
```

Now if you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    A       flag
0   1.00    0
1   1.00    1
2   1.00    1
3   1.00    1
4   0.91    5
5   2.00    1
6   2.00    1
7   2.00    0
8   2.00    1
```

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas , this is example data , here we know that the value greater is 0.91 in real data if we dont know exact value